# Log-Sobolev Inequalities for convex bodies

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, convex-geometry

For a measure $\mu$ supported on a convex body $K$, what are the conditions on $\mu$ and $K$ to satisfy a Log-Sobolev inequality of the form:
$$\int f^{2} \log f^{2}\,d\mu -\int f^{2}\,d\mu \log\left(\int f^{2}\,d\mu\right)\leq \frac{2}{c}\int |\nabla f|^{2}d\mu,$$
for all $f\in C^{1}(K)$ ?

I would appreciate any reference or a solution for the above question.

Comment: Is that log(f^2) or (log(f))^2?

Comment: @DarshRanjan It's $\log(f^2)$.